# What is behind the steel gates at prophet Mohammed's Grave (PBUH)?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, grave

What is actually behind the steel gates at Prophet Muhammad's Grave (PBUH) in Medina?

Is it visible if I look through the steel gates?

I heard it is so secure with concrete wall around the Prophet Muhammad's grave (PBUH) even saudi King cant access it.

[image]

Comment: For the record, now people cannot get close to this steel gate as shown in the picture. There is a concrete barrier (~3' high) and some security personals, making sure that no one can get close. This is only for ordinary people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Behind the gold mesh and black curtains are the graves of the prophet Mohammad, Abu Bakr, and Umar Ibn Al-Khattab. Because of the curtains you cannot actually see the graves, and no photos exist that I know of. The grave was first walled off during the reign Umar.

Answer (score -1):

Behind the gold gates is a huge wall then curtain another wall so thick no one can get in . Also dug deep underground to stop people going underground to dig the bodys  even if they tried the ground will swallow them up

The graves of mohammed and the other two need I mention as they plotted and poisoned our beloved prophet are buried without a grave stone only mud . There is said to be an empty grave for jesus . Only Allah  knows best

Comment: What proof do you posses that the daughter of Prophet Muhammad(saw) nor his other family members were aware of. Beware of Allah for you are blaming two men for murder whom Allah Himself has declared to be men of Paradise and beloved to the Prophet. Infact they were part of his family by marriages too.